# Access a list value in a content webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have added a HTML Content webpart to my discussion thread view item page .

In the discussion thread list, I have added a new column called VideoName.

Now, when a user clicks on a discussion list item, on the details page, I want to dynamically lookup the VideoName(in a HTML content webpart) field and display the correct video that belongs to that thread using some JavaScript. I have thought of passing the VideoName as Query String parameter but don't know if this is possible in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Is this column shown on the item display page? if so, you can find it using Javascript functions and play each time the page loads

Comment: Yes it is in the details page. But I need to show the column in another content webpart as a parameter. Is this possible?

Comment: please explain in more details, the other content web part is on the same page? if so, why can't you run JS from it?